manga where the mc used to be an S rank adventurer then died and reincarnated but the human race has been enslaved by other races and monsters
In this world Every race and monster has their level limit, they can't raise their level like humans, while the human race doesn't but all humans forget that they can raise their level. So all humans have their level stagnant at level 1, this world has a system like manga in general which is similar to games.

this sound like a typical CN manhua with system + non human race war.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Mostly black and white
